# Unable to store session data into cookie and send back to server

Tags: ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4, cookies

Currently, I am working on signup functionality of a web application using Rails 4. Basically, the working flow will be as follow:

1. User fills in signup form and submit it to server
2. Signup request then will be handled by **create** method of **UserController**
3. Session data will be then stored in cookie and sent back to server to persist session data among requests.

However, when observing **response header** after trying to signup, I did not see **set-cookie** property. And, in fact, current cookies does not store any session data for server to realize session. Below is my code:

**users_controller.rb**

```
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
     ...
     def create
        @user = User.create(user_params)

        # set session
        log_in @user

        render 'index'
     end
    ...
  end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
     # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
     # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
     protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
     include SessionHelper
  end
```

**session_helper.rb**

```
  module SessionHelper


     # Log in a given user
     def log_in(user)
        # Send session stored in a temporary cookie to browser
        # By default, cookie will be storage mechanism for session
        session[:user_id] = user.id
     end
```

I will be thankful if someone can explain the root of problem and give me some workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without the parameter `with: :null_session` in `application_controller`?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I did try it as well. But things still did not work out

Answer (score 0):

everyone.

After having done some research, I had found out a workaround by adding **skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token** in **UserController** to bypass **authenticity_token** as follow:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    # To make the sesson get reset
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
end
```

Thank you so much for your attention.

Regards.